# Bind named datagridview column with specific column in datatable

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datatable

I added some columns into datagridview by using the following code:

```
dataGridView1.Columns.Add("name");
dataGridView1.Columns.Add("age");
dataGridView1.Columns.Add("salary");
```

I have datatable that contains data from stored procedure

`select col1,col2,col3 from emp`

I know the traditional way to bind datagridview with datatable or dataset ,but the problem that I rebuilt datagridview where I put multi Headers and I merged some headers together so I want way to bind specific datatable column with specific datagridview column like

```
dataGridView1.column("Name") = dt.column("col1");
```

Comment: What technology is this - Windows Forms, WPF, ASP.NET, Silverlight...?

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for the [`DataGridViewColumn.DataPropertyName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.datapropertyname(v=vs.110)) property.

```
dataGridView1.Columns["Name"].DataPropertyName = "col1";
```